# deploy java project on Google App Engine

Tags: java, google-app-engine

i am new to Google app engine. i have a java project which implement a Http Server using

```
org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpServer
```

the structure of my priject:

[image]

mu project is not a web application that has war files. it just has src and resource.
how can i deploy it on google app engine? i can not set application ID because it has not appengine-web.xml .

Comment: App Engine for Java is a Servlet container, so your code or the framework you use needs to be implemented as Servlets, Servlet Filters or JSPs. You cannot run arbitrary servers like Grizzly on App Engine. If you cannot change your application to use Servlets, consider take a look at Google Compute Engine, https://developers.google.com/compute/.

Comment: There's also a tutorial around App Engine, Java and Maven. That should have some pointers on how to restructure your application to work on App Engine: https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/java/gettingstarted/introduction